# Uninstall IntelliJ from linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, terminal, uninstallation

I used to do my coding on a Chromebook (which I very quickly found was a horrible idea) before I upgraded my laptop. I successfully uninstalled the python IDE I was using (Spyder3) using

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove spyder3
```

in my terminal. I did the same thing to uninstall any remaining python files. However, I cannot figure out the correct way to do the same thing for Intellij. I have tried using `dpkg --list` to find the right file but I am seriously inexperienced in using the terminal. A classmate helped me with my original downloads, so I didn't even do those myself. Is there any advice out there on how I can figure out the right way to remove this? For reference I used IntelliJIdea2019.3.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of adding new functionalities to linux.

The unistall procedure depends on how you installed IntelliJ IDEA on your computer.

- If you installed it with snap : use `snap remove <package>` to remove the snap package.
- If it was installed manually by extracting the files from an archive to the /opt/idea , or any other directory, just remove the `/opt/idea` folder with the `rm` command.

This might help : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html

Comment: My classmate installed it through my terminal, but other than that I do not know the exact method that was used. I have been to that link and tried using the ```rm``` command, but it always says "no such file or directory".

Comment: Well it will be difficult to give you the answer that suits you the best because as you said, you don't really know how was installed this software. However, I recommend you to take a look at the basic linux commands, you will learn how to move between folders, create, edit and remove files, then you should be able to solve this issue.

Comment: @Shayla It might be that you have `intelliJ` in your `opt` directory, so you would have to remove that directory: `rm -rf /opt/intelliJ`.